# Find a random question

Tags: feature-request, searching

Is there a way to find a random question?

Currently in ask Ubuntu there are 5 question category tabs/tags : newest, faq votes, active, unanswered.

I found it quite useful to be a **random**  category tab/tag

Could it be a possible feature request?

**Edit**: Still I haven't found a way to look at random questions!

Comment: I don't think it would be useful at all. Do you have any specific use case in mind?

Comment: The only use case I could see for this is unanswered, select at random, weight older questions.  It might help clear up old questions without as much rage-quit on only getting vtc too localised questions.

Comment: Yeah,just join in the cleanup process ,you will get random unansweres posts

Comment: @jokerdino I wanted to answer some questions and I didn't find a way to search into random questions. 
However I don't understand why my answer is down-voted..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say your *answer* was downvoted, but if you're talking about the 4 downvotes (and 3 upvotes) this *question* got, this is an expression of whether or not people agree with the feature you are proposing. [Voting doesn't mean the same thing here on meta that it does on main](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#vote-differences), and the downvotes you've received here don't mean your question is poorly written, contains false information, is fundamentally unanswerable, or anything like that.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for the heads up, I had the impression that was not so easy to "enter" meta askubuntu.

Comment: When you say "to 'enter' meta askubuntu," what do you mean? Are you referring to the [5 minimum rep](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) needed to post here? Or something else?

Comment: @EliahKagan Well, actually yes I thought it would be nice to discuss about a feauture/issue in askubuntu and I thought (after searching) posting here. But I don't if I'll do it so easily again.

Comment: You were right to post about this here. Like I said, downvotes on meta *don't mean the same thing as on the main site*. Downvotes don't mean people think you shouldn't have asked your question, nor do they mean people think it's a bad question. There has already been some productive discussion of your proposal and hopefully there will be even more. By posting this meta question, you've contributed positively to the AskUbuntu community. **Please continue posting your site-related questions and ideas here on meta!**

Comment: @abcd How can I do that?

Comment: @pl1nk There are a number of ways you can help review and maintain questions and answers on this site. Seeing as you have enough reputation to do so, you may want to give the [review](http://askubuntu.com/review) portion of the site a look to view posts which are identified as most in need of review.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 - What are the criteria for the question in review ? I could find something in FAQ.
I hope that I don't make it a never ending comment discussion, but I guess it's not an issue in meta askubuntu.